# log4j PatternLayout time since last log

Tags: log4j

We are looking at moving to log4j from a home made logging framework (from the 90s) and I'm having trouble configuring the pattern to match our existing logs.

We output with each log line the time since the previous log line. This often helps us to determine where a delay is in a customer system without doing any calculations. I can't see how to do this without writing a whole new Layout.

Can this be done with a PatternLayout?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by log4j. I assume it's because performance, log4j has very high throughput and such a functionality cause significant scalability drop.

However you can still achieve this by processing already produced log, probably some elastic or database based appender would suite better.

Comment: It would only be a performance hit if it had to be perfectly accurate wouldn't it? The framework already has to read the current time - this would just need a single long stored there - making it volatile or an AtomicLong would make it accurate but otherwise it would be fast and nearly always accurate surely?

Comment: @mjaggard : The issue is that the messages would have to be formatted in the correct order, the same the time delta is achieved. In other words less or more it would have to synchronize on single CPU - that would affect the scalability.

Comment: Again, doesn't this only matter if you care about millisecond accuracy. Otherwise, data will be eventually correct - and eventually in this case would be very quick because it will happen as soon as the processor cache line is written back to main memory?